# Reading contents of DB for channel.id

Tags: node.js, discord.js, better-sqlite3

My logging command needs a channel to send messages, I do this with a `>logging #channel-here` command, it stores on better-sqlite3, my issue is I am not sure on how to read the contents and convert it to a channel.
[image: logging]

I have been working on this for several days, and I have tried several different things, this was my latest attempt

```
  const id = sql.prepare(`SELECT channel FROM logging WHERE guildid = ${message.guild.id};`).get();
  const logs = client.channels.get(id);
  if (!logs) return;
  logs.send(`A message was deleted`);
```

`const logs =` needs to `=` the channel id that you see in the channel record if the guildid record matches the one that the message was deleted in.

Comment: Can you elaborate what `client.getScore()` actually is? I don't think it's a Discord.js function. Normally you would get the guild via `client.guilds.find()`and then you can do the same for the channel based on the found guild.

Comment: I have no idea why that was there, must have copied the wrong bit. I have updated the question with my current attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving the channels mention you should save the channels id.
`<#channel-id>` is used to mention a channel, but `discord.js` `<guild>.channels.get()`, takes only the ID.
So you should only store the Channel Id in the Database, in your code for `>logging #channel-here` just use `const mentionedchannel = message.mentions.channels.first();`
and then into your DB just write the `mentionedchannel.id`, then your `.get()` should work!

Comment: `message.mentions.channels.first();` Still stores the channel as `<#529093571815669770>`

Comment: Use `message.mentions.channels.first().id`